# Get the link between parent table and child table , or grand child table and store in a java object

Tags: java, sql

Given a parent and child table name, I want to find the primary key, foreign key link, when there are multiple levels of primary key forein key relation in between them. Like for example 
a childtable is a grandchild of a parent table.

I have a query that retrieves a bunch tables with its immediate parent table that has primary key foreign key relation. 
For example

now I given my parent table is table and my grand child is childtable, I want to get the path and primary keys.

I understand, this is a tree like data structure and I ve gone through some posts which created a tree structure , however, I am not able to store beyond level 1.

Please suggest.

Thanks

public class Traverse {

```
String parent = "parent";
String theChild = "child";
List < String > parents = new ArrayList < > ();

@Autowired

private Queue < Map < Map < Integer, String > , Boolean >> nodeMap = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue < > ();
private List < Map < Map < Integer, String > , String >> finalNodeMap = new LinkedList < > ();


public void run() throws SQLException {

    parents = getParents(theChild);

    for (String s: parents) {
        HashMap < Integer, String > level = new HashMap < > ();
        level.put(0, s);
        HashMap < Map < Integer, String > , Boolean > visited = new HashMap < > ();
        visited.put(level, false);
        nodeMap.add(visited);

    }
    recurseRun();

}

public void recurseRun() throws SQLException {
    Iterator it = nodeMap.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && nodeMap.size() != 0) {

        for (Map < Map < Integer, String > , Boolean > m: nodeMap) {
            for (Map.Entry < Map < Integer, String > , Boolean > entry: m.entrySet()) {

                if (entry.getValue().equals(false)) {
                    parents.clear();
                    parents = getParents(entry.getKey().values().toArray()[0].toString());
                    if (parents.size() != 0) {
                        for (String s: parents) {
                            HashMap < Integer, String > level = new HashMap < > ();
                            level.put(Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey().keySet().toArray()[0].toString()) + 1, s);
                            HashMap < Map < Integer, String > , Boolean > visited = new HashMap < > ();
                            visited.put(level, false);
                            nodeMap.add(visited);
                            Map < Map < Integer, String > , String > map = new HashMap < > ();
                            map.put(entry.getKey(), s);
                            finalNodeMap.add(map);

                        }

                    }

                }
                nodeMap.remove(m);
            }


        }


    }
}

private List < String > getParents(String s) throws SQLException {
    return getParentTableList(s);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, @prash, it sounds like you might need to return each intermediate key and build a 'tree' yourself with results.  Or you could use a relational db model framework (e.g. Hibernate) to model your relationships in code.  Perhaps you can share some example code to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I used the above code to create a list of Map of Maps, that has level and table name(node) and its corresponding parent.

Comment: How can I get that result into a tree format, is what I am looking for.